# Special case on counting in a string of 7 letters

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following question:

Suppose $S_7$ is the set of all strings of length seven that can be formed with the letters $A, B, C, D, E, F$ and $G$ when repetitions are allowed.

How many strings in $S_7$ contain $D, E$ and $F$ in consecutive positions?

I was given the answer $5 \cdot 7^4 - 3\cdot 7$

I know where $5\cdot 7^4$ comes from. Please explain what does $3 \cdot 7$ mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are $3\cdot7$ strings that contain *two* copies of the substring DEF: they are the strings XDEFDEF, DEFXDEF, and DEFDEFX, where X can be any of the $7$ letters. Each of these $21$ strings is counted twice in the $5\cdot7^4$ term, so each must be subtracted once to get the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't be carefull, you'll count 2 time the string DEFADEF

There is $3\times7$ strings with two time the substring DEF inside, so you need to remove these as they are counted two time